# Adjective for "animosité"

Tags: vocabulaire

I can't find the adjective corresponding to

> animosité

The closest one I found is

> fielleux/fielleuse

But do anyone knows the correct one, which use the same stem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no"correct" adjective.

*Animosité* is not a nominalisation of some hypothetical adjective, but a **direct borrowing from Latin** *animositas*. The same root eventually gave *animal* and *animus*, but despite being etymologically connected, these words are semantically unrelated to *animosité*.

Comment: I had a bit of a brainfart here, since I meant "animation", not "animus".

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree with @Circeus, regarding the fact that there is not any adjective **etymologically** corresponding with *animosité*.
And this precisely answered the OP since it stated "which use the same stem".

But it's always possible (even if also always debatable :) to propose an adjective closer corresponding from the viewpoint of the significance.

Then *fielleux* is not appropriate : it partly brings the sense of hypocrisy, while *animosité* always assumes a frank behaviour.
This is clearly attested by all the definitions found in the TLFI:

> **Manifestation** d'un sentiment vif et parfois durable de malveillance systématique
>
> **Emportement** violent dans une discussion, une polémique, un **affrontement**

Even when used figuratively:

> Grande vivacité

So these adjectives might be better candidates (though they don't fully yield the combination of nuances of *animosité*, and should be chosen depending on the context): *vindicatif*, *malveillant*, *emporté*, *haineux*, *agressif*, *hostile*...